# "Conversion to non-scalar type is requested" error on linux terminal using cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I faced an issue when i try to generate CodeLite using CMake. I encountered it during 'make -j4' step. it shows "Conversion to non-scalar type is requested".

```
'''    
[ 68%] Built target codelitephp    
[ 68%] Built target codelite-make
[ 69%] Built target codelite-terminal    
[ 83%] Built target wxCrafter    
[ 83%] [ 83%] [ 83%] Building CXX object LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/CompilerMainPage.cpp.o
Building CXX object LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/CompilersFoundDlgBase.cpp.o
Building CXX object LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/CompilersFoundDlg.cpp.o    
[ 83%] Building CXX object LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/CompilersFoundDlg_liteeditor_bitmaps.cpp.o    
[ 83%] Building CXX object LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/CompilersModifiedDlg.cpp.o
/home/osboxes/Desktop/codelite-13.0/LiteEditor/CompilerMainPage.cpp: In member function ‘void CompilerMainPage::InitializeTools()’:    
/home/osboxes/Desktop/codelite-13.0/LiteEditor/CompilerMainPage.cpp:543:76: error: conversion from ‘wxPGIterator<wxPGProperty,wxPropertyGridPageState>’ to non-scalar type ‘wxPGIterator<const wxPGProperty,const wxPropertyGridPageState>’ requested    
     wxPropertyGridConstIterator iter = m_pgMgrTools->GetGrid()->GetIterator();   
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~   
[ 83%] Building CXX object LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/ConfigManagerBaseDlg.cpp.o    
make[2]: *** [LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/CompilerMainPage.cpp.o] Error 1    
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....    
make[1]: *** [LiteEditor/CMakeFiles/codelite.dir/all] Error 2    
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

'''

Anyone can help me resolve the issue? I followed [this GitHub link](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/wiki/Compile-and-install-codelite10-in-centOS7). It seems like there might be something wrong with the 'cmake' step. Greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me solve it!

Comment: Your OS name / version is missing. Please edit your question. .... Please note that codelite-13.0 requires wxgtk **3.1** .

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't seem to be related to CMAKE rather than to the actual compilation.
I don't know the library personally but as far as I can tell from the wiki page you shared, it seems maybe those instructions might be outdated because it's dated from 2018 but there's recent changes in the library.

I would check the dependencies versions to see if they match with the one that the maintainer specifies in the README.md

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when trying to compile CodeLite 13 on CentOS 7.6 clone OS. Manage to solve it by replacing following code string on line 543 of CompilerMainPage.cpp file,
located in "LiteEditor" subfolder:

```
wxPropertyGridConstIterator iter = m_pgMgrTools->GetGrid()->GetIterator();
```

by following code statement:

```
const wxPropertyGrid* pgrid = m_pgMgrTools->GetGrid();
wxPropertyGridConstIterator iter = pgrid->GetIterator();
```

Save that file and repeat compilation. In my case issue was solved and I could use now CodeLite 13 for my development projects (unfortunately CodeLite not available in rpm format for CentOS 7.x)